# cesium how to display multiple camera?

Tags: cesiumjs

Can cesium in a scene to display multiple angles of the camera screen? And hope that the camera's picture with the rotation of the model synchronization changes.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have two cameras in a scene, however you could have two viewer instances thus having multi-cameras.

I used two viewers to indicate the world map along with an object that was moving. The 2nd viewer showed the point of view of the moving object.

You'd need to handle the viewers entities separately.

```
var v1 = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer1');

var v2 = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer2', {
    sceneMode : Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE2D
});

var redEllipse = {
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-103.0, 40.0),
    name : 'Red ellipse on surface',
    ellipse : {
        semiMinorAxis : 250000.0,
        semiMajorAxis : 400000.0,
        material : Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5)
    }
};

v1.entities.add(redEllipse);
v2.entities.add(redEllipse);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution works if you modify the "html body & css" part as follows:

```
<style>
  @import url(../templates/bucket.css);
   </style>
    <div id="cesiumContainer1" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:50%; bottom:0; left:0;"></div>
    <div id="cesiumContainer2" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:50%; bottom:0; right:0;"></div>

    <div id="loadingOverlay"><h1>Loading...</h1></div>
    <div id="toolbar"></div>
```